# XCode utility template crashes

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode-template

following the next exact steps i get a SIGKILL from xcode :

> 1. creating a new Utility Based iOS template for the iphone
> 2. building and launching it with the emulator
> 3. pressing the home button
> 4. double pressing home and closing my application
> 5. relaunching it

i can't seem to understand why it is crashing, does anyone manage to reproduce it and has a clue about what is happening ?

thanks !!

EDIT - apparently this is normal behaviour, found a related post [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2788279?threadID=2788279&tstart=120v) hope it helps.

Comment: I just created an utility based app using Xcode 4. I couldn't reproduce it. What are the versions of XCode and SDK you're using?

Comment: i am using xcode 4 4A304a and sdk 4.3 8F190

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for a while. 
I figured out that this happens when you delete an IBOutlet in your h file, but you don't delete the connection in the .xib file.

Go to your .xib (or storyboard), click on File's Owner, and in the "Connections Inspector" (far right, looks like a circle with a right arrow) tab of the "Utilities Inspector" (far right sidebar in xcode 4.x) make sure you don't have any unused IBOutlets sitting there.

It worked for me...